# airlink wifi dongle not associating

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless

I'm having issues getting my wifi dongle to associate to a network.

I did the usual `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` with the Raspberry Pi ethernet plugged in for a full update. My understanding is that the Airlink 101 Wireless N 150 Mini-USB Adapter drives come with the Raspbian distribution.

My /etc/network/interfaces has

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf looks like:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="myID"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    psk="myPassphrase"
}
```

I have something like eight machines connecting to the network, so I'm pretty sure the network is fine and the passphrase is right. When I do an `iwconfig` I get:

```
WLAN0    unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
         Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
         Sensitivity:0/0
         Retry:off   RTS The:off  Fragment fhr:off
         Power Management:off
         Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
         Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
         Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0  Missed beacon:0

lo       no wireless extensions.

eth0       no wireless extensions.
```

That seems like the wifi dongle is working fine (I get this whether I restart or if I start from scratch and do an `ifup wlan0`). In addition, doing an `iwlist scan` gives me a valid list of some 9 networks in my area including the one I'm trying to connect to (the ESSID: field is the same as the one in my wpa_supplicant.conf).

I think the successful scan tells me that the wifi dongle is working fine, but I've got some configuration wrong for connecting to my network. Additionally pointing me in that direction is that when I run `wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` it returns `Failed to read or parse configuration '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'.` Also, if I `ifdown wlan0` followed by `ifup wlan0` I get:

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENDOCEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENDOCEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

Am I doing something wrong in my configuration?

Comment: I don't know much about this. But, I did get mine working after many hours of struggling. One thing that help me was to use -dd on the command line. See  http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_supplicant